# Is there a move topological brush in Blender?

Tags: sculpting, zbrush

I can't find a way to change falloff to use the distance on the topology rather than the absolute distance. 
It is very difficult to sculpt things like fingers. When I grab one finger it automatically moves the others.
zBrush does have this brush, but I'd really prefer to stay in blender.

Is there some option/addon/workaround to this?

Comment: Pablo Dobarro is currently working on plenty new features and improvements for sculpting. I'm not familiar with the zBrush behavior, but it could be a feature that will be included in one of the next Blender versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is not counter part to topological falloff with the sculpt tools AFAIK. There is a topological option in the move, scale, rotate tools when you enable Proportional Editing called Connected Only.

If you need to use the sculpt tools, use masking or hide parts of the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar functionality.  A workaround for this is masking off the area that you want unaffected.  This is also useful for areas like the lips.

Answer (score 0):

While there doesn't seem to be a good option for this within Blender itself, I've been very pleased with using the GoB Blender addon that allows you to easily cross-edit any mesh within Zbrush and Blender at the same time.